# I can't find proper "old" "ex4 to mq4 decompiler"?

Tags: decompiler, metatrader4

I know that there were ex4 to mq4 decompilers for old version of MT4, but can't find anything which works properly. In fact, all of them which are on the internet are viruses or malware.

I could find some codes for it in github.
https://github.com/FX31337/ex4_to_mq4_cli/

But this is wrapper, not decompiler, so needs ex4_to_mq4.exe itself for working.

My purpose is to recover my code from ex4 which was made in 2015 and lost by accident.

Please help if you have it or some experiences.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://github.com/FX31337/ex4_to_mq4_cli/issues/8#issuecomment-667730347